# How to reload the tab with same domain but different port

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, reload

I have been researching this problem and while there's lots of posts on various forums about similar problems, none of the problems or solutions exactly match mine.

I want to reload the parent page who opened a 3rd party UI. The problem is the 3rd party UI closes after i click confirm and i have no power to change those codes.
that is why i cant use `window.opener` of javascript

My own ui has a different port than my backend that is why i cant use local storage

3rd option is to use cookies but i dont want my UI to always check for the cookie if it was changed. Is there another way i can reload my UI?

Comment: `window.location.port = your_port`

Comment: this snippet will only get the port of the current window right?